# Property 'user' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ name: string; }>'

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

i'm new with TypeScript. I'm trying to use TypeScript with Redux but i'm blocked with this error: `Property 'user' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ name: string; }>'.`
I was going step by step with tutorial on Youtube but it's not working on my project. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import React from 'react';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    name: '',
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state: { user: { user: any } }) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: can you share the link to the tutorial?

Comment: @TobiasS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMzhWXr9ass&t=1286s

Answer (score 1):

Redux will infer the type of `state` (in your reducers) from the `initialState` value passed to the `createSlice` function, here:

```
...
initialState: {
  name: '',
}, // type of your state is: { name: string } - notice how it does not have a `user` property!
...
```

In your reducers, you will get a `WritableDraft` instance of the state as the first argument, like so:

```
logout: (state: WritableDraft<{ name: string }>) => {
  state.user = null; // 'user' property does not exist in your state type! (as defined in the `initialState`)
},
```

---

To accomplish what I **think** you're trying to accomplish, all you have to do is abstract the `name` variable inside of a `user` property, like so:

```
...
initialState: {
  user: { name: '' }
},
reducers: {
  login: (state, action) => {
    state.user = action.payload;
  },
  logout: (state) => {
    state.user = null;
  },
}
...
```

At this point I would recommend explicitly typing your state and action payloads.

E.g.:

```
export type User {
  name: string
}

export type UserState = {
  user: User | null
}
```

... and in your reducers:

```
login: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
  state.user = action.payload; // action.payload will be of type 'User'
},
logout: (state) => {
  state.user = null
}
```

Anyway, it seems you missed something from the tutorial since in your own code you have a selector defining your state as `state: { user: { user: any } }`. Explicitly defining your state type, like above, should help mitigate these issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The data shape of the `user` state slice is `{ name: string }`.

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    name: '',
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.name = '';
    },
  },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state: { user: { name: string } }) => state.user;

const store = configureStore({ reducer: combineReducers({ user: userSlice.reducer }) });
console.log(store.getState());
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('selectUser:', selectUser(store.getState()));
});

console.log(store.dispatch(login('John')));
```

Logs:

```sh
{ user: { name: '' } }
selectUser: { name: 'John' }
{ type: 'user/login', payload: 'John' }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've cross checked your code and its fine.

Change the version of redux-toolkit to a previous one, in my case, I used `1.8.0` and everything started working again.

Or delete node_modules and run `npm install` or `yarn`