# Property 'user' does not exist on type WritableDraft

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux userSlice that is attempting to get user data from the store.

client/src/redux/features/userSlice.ts

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { User } from "../../interfaces/user";
import userApi from "../../apis/user";

export const getUser = createAsyncThunk("user/getUser", async (_, thunkApi) => {
  try {
    const response = await userApi.getUser();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ error: "user not initialized" });
  }
});

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    profile: {
      ipAddress: "",
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    getUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { getUser: getUserAction } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

I am able to successfully log out the user in the API interface:

client/src/apis/user.ts

```
const userApi = {
  getUser: async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/:ipAddress");
      const user = await response.json();
      console.log("in user api:", user);
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user:", error);
      return error;
    }
  },
};

export default userApi;
```

`console.log("in user api:", user);` returns the following:

```
in user api: 
Object { user: {…} }
​
user: Object { _id: "65c1f831b5759dc19442396d", ipAddress: "::ffff:127.0.0.1", createdAt: "2024-02-06T09:13:21.391Z", … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

However, I am seeing an error on `state.user = action.payload` which states `Property 'user' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ profile: { ipAddress: string; }; }>'`

The user types I've defined are as such:

client/src/interfaces/user.ts

```
export type User = {
  profile: UserProfile
}

export type UserProfile = {
  ipAddress: string
}

export type UserState = {
  user: User
}
```

My redux state is showing only the initial state being fulfilled, but not the ipAddress of the user, as expected.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'user' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ name: string; }>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72048120/property-user-does-not-exist-on-type-writabledraft-name-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `user` property in the `userSlice` state. The `userSlice` state ***is*** a `User` type. If `getUser` is setting the "user" then it should replace the state. Return `action.payload` since `state = action.payload` is invalid, you can't reassign the draft state.

Example:

```js
const initialState: User = {
  profile: { ipAddress: "" },
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      return action.payload; // <-- return User value
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with your `WritableDraft` interface. Could you update your question to include that interface definition? Perhaps you are conflating the `WritableDraft` `profile` attribute with a `user` attribute?

Consider the following change:

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    profile: {
      ipAddress: "",
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    getUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      // This is the change here, note that your initial state has a
      // profile not a user
      state.profile = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```